# How can I add the searchbar at the top of the page

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, searchbar

Briefly this is code of my Xamarin HomePage.xaml

```
<ContentPage>

 <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar
            x:Name="mySearchBar"
            SearchButtonPressed="mySearchBar_ButtonPressed">
        </SearchBar>
    </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
               <!-- Label and entries here -->
                <StackLayout>
                    <!-- Label and entries here -->
                </StackLayout>
                 <!-- Buttons and a listview here -->
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage>
```

But I want to add the searchbar top of the page, the blue bar. How can i do that?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: this is not possible out of the box. You have to create it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Refer this following [link](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) for MaterialSearchView.**

**Also for using different search functionality refer [this link](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview).**

Hope it helps.

Comment: @eaege If you found this answer helpful, do accept the answer, so that others get benefited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want the search bar at the top of navigation bar. For this you have to perform custom rendering. Find this [blog link](http://blog.xhackers.co/xamarin-forms-contentpage-with-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar/) to achieve this :

[Github source link](https://github.com/rohitvipin/Xamarin-Forms-Custom-Renderer-Samples)

Hope this helps !